# Landlord access into apartment

Tags: united-kingdom

I went to a viewing of an apartment, and someone was **already** living in the one that we were showed. They weren't there during the viewing.

Is this allowed? The landlord said they gave the person a 24-hour notice. Could the current tenant refuse this? This happened in Liverpool, UK.

Comment: This is quite common around the world (I can't speak specifically for the UK though), particularly if the current tenant has already given notice that they are going to leave.  Landlord gets permission from the tenant to show the house/apartment to show a prospective tenant through.  This makes it easier to let the apartment as soon as the current tenant has left so there's minimal gap in rent payments.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better fit for [Law.SE].  In any event, if the current tenant has given permission for the showing, it's certainly legal.  The permission might have been given as a contract term in the lease.  There may also be provisions in the law that allow the landlord to show the apartment without the tenant's permission; I presume that's what you're asking about, and I don't know the answer with respect to English or UK law.

Comment: Agree with @phoog, not an expat-related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but landlords are allowed to get into their apartments, even when occupied by a tenant, for specific things. Included in the list is doing essential repairs and showing the apartment to potential tenants. Usually there is a requirement to give a certain amount of notice.

A tenant could reasonably ask for the showing to be at a different time, but couldn't simply refuse to admit the landlord.